# Create SQL VM with Mixed Mode Authentication using PowerShell Script

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, authentication, azure-powershell

I am trying to create a SQL Server 2016 Windows 2016 Virtual Machine in Azure using an unattended PowerShell script that I am running remotely but I cannot find a way to set SQL to Mixed-Mode Authentication using PowerShell.

I can get the Virtual Machine spun up with SQL Installed but I can't find any commands that will perform the change to Mixed-Mode Authentication (even though this is possible using the SQL Server Configuration Blade in the Azure GUI).

Is anyone able to provide some insight into how to set this up?

Many Thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1: Using PowerShell and Template

You can get the commands directly from the Azure Portal by creating a template. Use this procedure:

1. Select new virtual machine named: `SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Windows Server 2016`
   [image]
2. fill the form.... In step 4 `Configure SQL Server setting`, you have the option to select the `SQL Authentication`. Select `Enable`.
   [image]
3. Click OK
4. In the last step you have the option to click `Create` or `Download template and parameters`. Select the second option `Download template and parameters`.
5. Download the Template and inside you have all the command using PowerShell and the Template JSON files

> Note! Don't forget to change the path to the template JSON if you want to execute it directly.

#### Option 2: Using T-SQL after the machine is ready

> Note! you can execute the script using PowerShell as well, if you have permission.

Login using the administrator and execute this:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Ronen, I used Option 2 with PowerShell running as an Administrator.

Comment: Awesome @DavoDestroyer :-) I am glad to hear this solve your issue. Please remember to close the thread by marking the answer ;-)